# pull full names and surname/surnames form the consecutive paragraphs in Excel / Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, nlp

First Things First: The macro is run from Excel VBA editor, but performs the biggest part of its job on the previously opened Word document, where it's goal is to find the full names of the people who are the contracting parties in the agreement being analized.

The issue I'm experiencing with the code is that it is variable number of words, that I need to pull from every consecutive paragraph. If the name is Will SMITH, then its two words I need to pull, when it's Carrie Ann MOSS, then it's three words, sometimes it can be Anna Nicole SMITH BURKE, than its four words but when it's Anna Nicole SMITH-BURKE, than its five words and so on.

The other idea to get this **full name** is, that it always ends with a coma, and this coma is always the first coma in this paragraph, where the full name appears.

ATTENTION !!! The Paragraphs we work with are not `ListParagraphs`. They are the normal/ordinary ones albeit indented and numbered. I get these contracts from people who don't care to use numbered list :-(
  So for the last time: The numbered list is not enabled on those paragraphs we work with.

This is how it looks like in Word and the selected words are the names and surnames that the macro is supposed to extract from the document - excluding the coma after the last surname.

[image]

```
Sub FindNamesCleanDraftWithLoop()
    'Variables declaration
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim Rng As Word.Range
    Dim RngStart As Word.Range
    Dim RngEnd As Word.Range

    Dim TextToFind1 As String
    Dim TextToFind2 As String
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assigning object variables
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set MySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Set MySheet = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    TextToFind1 = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    TextToFind2 = "- ad."

    'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
    startPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind1) - 1    'here we get 1421, we're looking 4 "TextToFind1"
    endPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind2) - 1      'here we get 2246, we're looking 4 "- ad."
    If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
    Debug.Print Rng.Paragraphs.Count

    If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
    Else
        'somewhere here I need your help to write some lines that will
        'recognize how many words need to be pulled to extract the full
        'name/names + surname/surnames and nothing else - we end on the first coma.
        For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs
            firstName = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))
            Debug.Print Para.Range.Words(1) & Para.Range.Words(2) & _
                        Para.Range.Words(3) & Para.Range.Words(4) & _
                        Para.Range.Words(5) & Para.Range.Words(6)
        Next Para
    End If
End Sub
```

There in the `For Each Para ... Next Para` loop, I need your help to write some lines that will recognize how many words need to be pulled to extract the **full name/names + surname/surnames and nothing else** - we end on the first coma - that means excluding the coma after the last surname.

Comment: First thought of me would be to go `RegEx`

Comment: RegEx solution wouldn't give reliable results*. There is whole field in science on this and problem is not trivial at all.
* think: what happens when you have person from Netherland or Belgium ? or case with double lastnames (not very rare case in Slavic world).

Comment: Yes. I work in Warsaw, so Slavic country is where I'm based and double surnames/last names is a standard for married woman here. But can't someone help me using this other path: which is extract everything from the beginning of the each paragraph up till the first coma in the paragraph being processed.

Comment: Aaah, you have case of structured text with known structure. Uf, I have number of ideas and would solve this in C# but can't talk in VBA. Here, you could also use XML / XPath approach to fetch only list items from XML structure of the document (docx is actually a zip, when you unpack it you'll see ~content.xml. From there you can fetch InnerText of each item/node and do String search for "," to take substring. But can't talk in VBA, so, no direct help from me :)

Comment: Fetching XML nodes of list items (by tag name) is good idea since it's more robust approach for recognizing list item from other textual content. And when you get InnerText of the node, you only need index of comma in the String.

Comment: In Excel VBA, to return the text from the start of the paragraph up to the first comma:  `Left(Para, InStr(Para, ",") - 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you want, if I have understood correctly.

If the `Number` and `Dot` are **NOT** part of the paragraph, then to extract the full name, you could use:

```
Debug.Print Left(Para, InStr(Para, ",") - 1)
```

If the `Number` and `Dot` **ARE** part of the paragraph, then:

```
   Dim Start As Long, Length As Long
Start = InStr(Para, ".") + 1
Length = InStr(Para, ",") - Start

Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, Start, Length))
```

If you want to split the capitalized portion of the name from the rest, post several samples of the actual strings as **TEXT** as I am unable to copy/paste your screenshots into Excel.

Comment: In my case the ```Number``` and ```Dot``` and ```Space``` are part of those paragraphs we work with.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually question on Natural Language Processing - NLP (as scientific field) - problem of Tokenization you already solved, but you are now facing with: Part of Sentence (POS) tagging (and construction of semantic Chunk-s). Issue of Person Identity recognition is one of first since very dawn of the discipline, so, there are many libraries for this, but I'm skeptic you'll find anything you can use from VBA that easy. Also, for comprehensive/robust solution you'll need proper lexicon with names and lastnames (suitable resource would be a Morpho-sintactic Lexicon/Dictionary, extracted only for PName LName tags).

To solve this, you'll have to do some research on keywords mentioned above. I have no experience with VBA, but asume C# and .NET would be the easiest to integrate. Therefore, Standford CoreNLP for .NET would be starting point I recon: https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html

Highly relevant lexical source for English:
https://wordnet.princeton.edu/

You can query WordNet lexicon using [WordNet.NET](https://www.ebswift.com/wordnetnet.html). I've used both and its very good resource&library.

Comment: There are also my libraries for .NET on GitHub and NuGet, follow my account info and check my blog if you like. But using more mature projects is much better idea.

Comment: Wou, now I see it's in Polish. Sorry, my bad. However, you can find WordNet lexicon for Polish and use it to detect names. I wasn't reading this question completely - this is much simpler than NLP issues bothering me :)